# What is the reason for these two for loop acting differently?

Tags: java, for-loop, infinite-loop

Hi can anyone help me with this?

First block of codes gives the output as intended.
But second one goes for infinite loop.
What is the reason?

Thank you.

**1.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Numbers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a starting number: ")
        int start = scan.nextInt();

        for(int a = start;a<=(start+10);a++)
        {
             System.out.println(a);
        }

    }
}
```

**2.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Numbers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a starting number: ")
        
        for(int start = scan.nextInt();start<=(start+10);start++)
        {
             System.out.println(start);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you continuously increase `start`, when will the condition `start<=(start+10)` ever become false?

Comment: The difference is one variable vs two variables.

Comment: The loop test is re-evaluated on each pass. The values are not "locked in" at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first block, `start` is a constant variable which has fixed value and the condition is between `a` and `start` (`a` keeps increasing `a++` and `start` won't change its value).

While in second block, the condition is between `start` and `start+10`, but `start` keeps increasing with `start++` in the loop function, which makes the loop is infinite (`start` keeps changing its value so `start<=(start+10)` is always true).

Comment: A "constant variable"?

Comment: @shawnt00 it just means "not changing" variable.

Comment: I realize what you mean. Perhaps saying it is fixed is sufficient. For an entry-level question I might argue that precise terminology becomes important.

Comment: Thank you @DrakeLiam. It was easy solution but I was having hard time visualizing it. Now I get it `a will always be smaller than a+10.` Thank you @shawnt00 for your support.

Answer (score 2):

This `for(int start = scan.nextInt();start<=(start+10);start++)` compares the changing variable to a changing value, which keeps the same distance ahead.
I.e. the value of `start` will always be lower than `start+10`, what you get is at first an endless loop. It can only terminate when values get so high that they cannot be represented anymore an strange things occur. At that point `start+10` might appear to be lower than 0 for example and hence seem also lower than `start` which not yet is past that weird border.

Comment: You mean this loop will be terminated after `start+10` value pass that weird border??

Comment: It can. If beyond that border the representation "looks negative" it should. But code should not rely on things like that. I am more of a C person, where overflowing a signed int is undefined behaviour aka "evil".

Answer (score 1):

In your second snippet of code

```
for(int start = scan.nextInt();start<=(start+10);start++)
{
    System.out.println(start);
}
```

You're comparing `start` to itself plus 10. Regardless what operation you're going to perform, nothing can't be equals to itself plus 10. `start` will always be lower than itself plus 10 and therefore producing an infinite loop. **It's a semantic error.** You should use a different variable to keep track of the loop, as you did in your first snippet, and a second one for the confrontation (`start` in your case).